# weird lines is showing when overlaying two div

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make a custom splitter which is a `<div>` between page1 and page2, but some weird lines is showing which I don't know where they came from, or how to hide them!

[image: spiltter.png] spiltter.png

[image: pattern1.png] pattern1.png
[image: snipshot] Snippedshot

```
 .zikzak, .splitter, .split-content
 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
 }
 .splitter
 {
    height:250px;
 }
 .split-content
 {

    margin-top:-50px;
    height:250px;
    background:url(img/pattern1.png) repeat;
 }
 .zikzak
 {
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="splitter">
    <div class="zikzak" style="background:url(img/spiltter.png) repeat-x"></div>
    <div class="split-content"></div>
    <div class="zikzak" style="background:url(img/spiltter2.png) repeat-x"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: the problem with you image called `spiltter.png`. Image edges are transparent not solid. filled the solid color on edges. I hope your problem should solved.

Comment: @KheemaPandey I just noticed that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with you image called `spiltter.png` As the image edges are transparent not solid, that's why you are getting strange behavior.

To solve this bug you have to filled image edges with solid color.